# how to change repeater row back color on checkbox check using java script asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater

I want to change back color of repeater row when a particular row check box is checked client side or whenever a row td is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that the simplest way is that you will need to output your markup in tabular format like below code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="trclass" style="width:100px">
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text=""/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

  <style type="text/css">
    .backg
    {
        background-color:Blue;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$='_CheckBox1']").click(function () {
                var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
                if (checked == true) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("backg");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("backg");
                }
            });
            $(".trclass").click(function() {
            if ($(':checkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).addClass("backg");
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("backg");
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

There is a minor flaw but let me know if this is what you are looking for and we can fix it.

**Edited:**
I have updated the tr click code. See if that's what you want. If not can you update your question to clarify when you want the row color to change exactly and if the checbox is affected on row click?

**Edit 2:** 
I came across [this link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/quick-tip-click-table-row-to-trigger-a-checkbox-click) which might be helpful.

Comment: @gbs: Gbs row also gets selected on clicking checkbox border and row back color changes keeping checkbox unchecked.

Comment: @Mohan: That was the flaw I knew of. So did you get it working or still having that issue?